# Replace, But Only Include Delimiters in Certain Cases

Tags: php, regex, string

In PHP, I need to replace a fixed prefix and suffix surrounding a variable value.

The quotes around the value are stripped, except if the value is a string.

```
[blargh="5"]                  =>   <potato chips=#5#>
[blargh="97"]                 =>   <potato chips=#97#>
[blargh="StackOverflow"]      =>   <potato chips=#"StackOverflow"#>
```

I know that somehow, I can use `preg_replace()` to do this, but I do not know how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Branch Reset: `(?| ... )`

The tricky part in your question is that for `"StackOverflow"` we include the quotes in the replacement, but for `"87"` we strip them. No fear, the branch reset feature handles that gracefully.

In the **[Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/dU5lQ3/13)**, see the substitutions at the bottom.

**Sample PHP Code**

```
$yourstring = '[blargh="5"] [blargh="97"] [blargh="StackOverflow"]';
$replaced = preg_replace('~\[blargh=(?|"(\d+)"|("[^"]*"))\]~',
                          '<potato chips=#\1#>', 
                          $yourstring);
echo $replaced;
```

**Output**

```
<potato chips=#5#> <potato chips=#97#> <potato chips=#"StackOverflow"#>
```

**Our Search Regex:**

```
\[blargh=(?|"(\d+)"|("[^"]*"))\]
```

**Our Replacement String**

```
<potato chips=#\1#>
```

**Explanation**

- `\[blargh=` matches literal chars
- In the branch reset `(?| .... )`, the groups all capture to Group 1
- `"(\d+)"` captures digits inside quotes to Group 1 (but don't capture the quotes)
- OR `|`
- `("[^"]*")` capture a complete `"quoted string"` to Group 1
- `\]` matches the closing bracket
- In the replacement, `<potato chips=#\1#>`, `\1` is a back-reference to Group 1

**Reference**

- [Branch Reset](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#branchreset)
- [perlre doc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)

Comment: Thanks. I added an edit to my question that has some code that I was using to test the method. I am having a problem with it. After running `preg_replace`, echoing the variable does not produce any result.

Comment: I edited your test code, it runs perfectly. However if it does not show in your browser, it is because the output is a `<tag>`, so make sure you EITHER look at the html source in the brower (Ctrl/Cmd + U) OR `echo htmlentities($replaced);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58399/discussion-between-zx81-and-davidb).

Comment: *slaps self in face* Of course it's not gonna show! I appologize for the stupidity in what I said. Viewing source shows it just fine.

Comment: Common problem. I often test in a php console so this doesn't happen. :) Is it working now?

Comment: How would I capture two separate groups?

Comment: Separate groups: multiple parentheses, e.g. `(a+)b(c+)` captures some as to Group 1 and bs to Group 2, to which you can refer as `\1`, `\2` etc Please see [Capture Group Numbering & Naming: The Gory Details](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-capture.html)

Comment: Okay. I need to split up the tag `[img=10x100]` where in this example, 10 is length and 100 is width. I've been messing with it for hours now with no success.

Comment: David, use `\[img=(\d+)x(\d+)\]`, but for future needs please ask new questions as it's really hard to troubleshoot any new problems to extended questions in the comments.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help, and thanks for the advice. I hesitate to ask new questions because I am at risk of being question banned at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expression using a [**callback**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) as well.

```
$text = '[blargh="5"] would convert, [blargh="97"] and [blargh="StackOverflow"]';

$text = preg_replace_callback('~\[blargh="([^"]*)"\]~', 
      function($m) {
         $which = is_numeric($m[1]) ? $m[1] : '"'.$m[1].'"';
         return '<potato chips=#' . $which . '#>';
      }, $text);

echo $text;
```

Output

```
<potato chips=#5#> would convert, <potato chips=#97#> and <potato chips=#"StackOverflow"#>
```

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what a callback function is.

Comment: +1 for callback. David, a callback function lets you build a complex replacement. For instance, within the callback function, you could if you wished talk to a database, retrieve data from Mars, and include it in your replacement—so it's very flexible. In this case, the anonymous function performs a test on the match, and, depending on whether it was a numeric value, returns one kind of replacement or another. It's a great technique to be aware of and you might want to use it at some later stage for your parser.

Comment: @zx81 Oh. There are instances where I want whole pieces of HTML to vary based on certain conditions. Until now I have been using heredoc with variables that I set beforehand. This sounds much more efficient.